# Multiple MYSQL Statements executed as a single statement

Tags: php, mysql, post, inner-join, union

I've got a bit of a problem with my code. I'm sure that it is something simple, but I just can't figure it out! I have been on tons of forums and have read several books... but every answer that I have worked to has failed. I almost guarantee that it's the way that I am using my syntax (and yes I know... procedural PHP is not really used anymore) but I am really a bit of a newbie to this and I am just trying to pick up the basics before moving onto OOP and PDO connections.

Could you please help me? At the moment I can get the user to select their date from the date picker and the results specifically from that date only will return... only problem is that the event is displaying the event_id as opposed to the name of the event that it relates to (1 = 5km run) for example.

Somehow I need to access the events table and pull the row that relates to that specific event_id.

I have normalized my database, and according to my tutor it looks ok. To give you an idea what it looks like - logins table (all user logins details), results table (a history of submitted events) events table (the events themselves).

On the results table the foreign keys are logins_id and the event_id. The primary key is the results_id in the results table and the only data stored here is the time and data (individual columns).

```
<?php // -----Stage 1. On submission of the form run the following -----//

    if (isset($_POST['submit_d'])) {
        $mydate = $_POST ['MyDate'];
        $my = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', ' ', $mydate);

        if ($mydate)  {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1");

            //This function will take the above query and create an array...
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                //With the array created above, I can create variables (left) with the outputted array (right)
                $logins_id3 = $row['logins_id'];
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM results where $logins_id3 AND date = $mydate ";

            /* ----- Here is the code that I want to use in conjunction with the above statement --->

            $query = "SELECT logins.username,events.event,results.time,results.date,logins.age,logins.gender
                FROM logins INNER JOIN results ON logins.logins_id=results.logins_id INNER JOIN events ON results.event_id=events.event_id 
                ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 10";

            */

            $resultz = mysql_query($sql);

            if( mysql_num_rows($resultz) ) {

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultz))  {
                    echo "<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Event</th><th>Time (HH:MM:SS)</th><th>Date (YY/MM/DD)</th><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th>
                        </tr><tr><td>".$username."</td>"
                        ."<td>".$row['event_id']."</td>"."<td>".$row['time']."</td>"." <td>".$row['date']."</td>"."<td>".$row['age']."</td>".
                        "<td>" $row['gender']."</td></tr></table>"; 
                }   
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The other thing I would like to do.. although this is not crucial, is to strip special characters from the input. Basically I'm using a jquery calendar picker and I want the user to be able to select their date in the 2014-05-26 format and the php to remove the - before it is submitted to the database, that way it doesn't effect the users experience but it will work with my current code.

Anyways sorry to waffle on, any help on either of these matters would be much appreciated!

Yours Sincerely:

Peter Scales.

Comment: put an `echo $sql; exit;` after the line that has your select. You will see that your select statement is wrong unless the `$logins_id3` variable has proper SQL code.

Comment: @ kuldeep- ok thats fine... how would you suggest i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join to get the data that relates to the event ID:

```
SELECT * FROM results r LEFT JOIN events e ON r.event_id = e.event_id WHERE ...
```

You can then select where "e.event_id = $event_id"; and the rest of your query logic.

You can also filter out any unwanted characters by using preg_replace: https://www.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much. Only problem is with the $logins_id3 not storing the data I want and as a result all users that submitted their results on that date are coming up as well... I only want the user that is currently logged in under the session $username. Any ideas??

Comment: If you have that value of $username mapped in any of your two tables you can just update your WHERE clause to include that as well: 'WHERE username = "' . $username . '" // rest of your query logic". That way, the query will only return results where the username is the value specified and the two keys (primary and foreign) match each other. Alternatively, you can send us the breakdown of your tables so we can help you build the query correctly.

Comment: You sir are a LEGEND! This is the query that done what I wanted - $sql = "SELECT logins.username,events.event,results.time,results.date,logins.age,logins.gender FROM logins INNER JOIN results ON logins.logins_id=results.logins_id INNER JOIN events ON results.event_id=events.event_id where username = '$username' AND date = $mydate ";